# Hide Button on Click and Show Second Button on Video End

Tags: javascript, html

First post ever on Stack Overflow!

I have a HTML5 video where I have removed the default controls and added a Play/Spin to Win button. Once clicked I need this button to disappear and then when the video finishes a second button to appear that links through to a new URL.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have so far is below:

```js
function playPause(btn, vid) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

```css
div#video_player_box {
  width: 550px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div#video_controls_bar {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

#playpausebtn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="video_player_box">
  <video id="my_video" width="550" height="300" autoplay>
    <source src="memory-of-a-woman.mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="video_controls_bar">
    <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause(this,'my_video')">Spin to Win</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... ☺ Do have a look at [tour]. It will give you a great info on [ask] and other key features of this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) of Video API to make this possible. Specifically, you need the `ended` event listener.

Also corrected the invalid reference.

```js
function playPause(btn, vid) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
  vid.onended = function () {
    console.log("Ended. Do something.");
    btn.style.display = "none";
  };
}

window.onload = function () {
  var vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
  vid.onended = function () {
    console.log("Ended. Do something.");
  };
};
```

```css
div#video_player_box {
  width: 550px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

div#video_controls_bar {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

#playpausebtn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="video_player_box">
  <video id="my_video" width="550" height="300" autoplay>
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/stream_of_water.webm">
  </video>
  <div id="video_controls_bar">
    <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause(this,'my_video')">Spin to Win</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So once the video is ended, the callback function will be triggered by the event. You can set the new source. Check out by running the snippet and let the video end and you will see the message popup in the console.